# How can I keep the select / select all / cut / copy / paste bar from appearing when I programmatically select text in UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I've got a few instances of `UITextField` that I've added to some cells in a `UITableView`. I'm using the `UITextField` delegate to select all text in the `textfield`, like so:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField selectAll:self];
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that I don't want the selection popup to appear the first time you touch the cell. I want to be able to edit the text, so I don't want to use `becomeFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [`UIMenuController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) and you can hide it using `- (void)setMenuVisible:(BOOL)menuVisible animated:(BOOL)animated` so after your `[textField selectAll:self];` call the above method to hide the menu.

**EDIT**

After a little search on google it seems that you will need to create a subclass of UITextField and override the `- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender` and return `NO` from this in order to hide the `UIMenuController`.

I can't test this right now since I'm not at my office but you should also try the following line `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;` before you start to implement a subclass of `UITextField`

Comment: I added this line:  [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];  It didn't seem to help.  To give a little more background, when a user touches a certain row in my tableview I create two textfields and add them to the cell as subviews.  The intent is to create two fields where a user can enter a minimum value and a maximum value. I want the existing text to be already selected so the user can just enter a value and save it, but when I select the text the menu appears and obscures other cells in an annoying way. Adding setMenuVisible:NO didn't seem to help.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but will this solution prevent the menu from appearing at all? I'd like to still be able to select and copy / paste text from the UITextField, but I just don't want to see it when I initially select the text using: [textField selectAll:self];
}